# jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js doesn't show Messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

i used **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js** for validation but it **does not show Warn messages**
, however validation works well .

how i can fix it ?
:)

And how I can change the messages language ?!

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

form

```
   <!-- beging form-->

            <form asp-action="AddUrl" method="post" id="formLink">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <select class="form-control" data-live-search="true" name="lessonsDD" id="lessonsDD" asp-for="LessonId">
                            <option value="">درس را انتخاب کنید</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="LessonId" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <select class="form-control" data-live-search="true" name="chapterDD" id="chapterDD" asp-for="ChapterId">
                            <option value="">فصل را انتخاب کنید</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="ChapterId" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Url" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input type="url" asp-for="Url" class="form-control" name="url" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Url" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                    <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="افزودن" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i used jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js for validation but it does not show Warn messages

You need to remove the name attribute of the inputs.

> And how I can change the messages language ?!

You can try to [configure data annotation localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dataannotations-localization) to use a shared resource file：

```
 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddViewLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o =>
                {
                    var type = typeof(SharedResources);
                    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                    var factory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
                    var localizer = factory.Create("SharedResources", assemblyName.Name);
                    o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (t, f) => localizer;

                });
```

Structure of SharedResources:

[image]

SharedResources.cs:

```
public class SharedResources
    {
    }
```

SharedResources.fr.resx:
[image]
Model:

```
public class LocalModel
    {
        public string LessonId { get; set; }
        public string ChapterId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

result:
[image]